# Installed AMD GPU drivers, then uninstalled, now can't get to desktop

Tags: drivers, tty, amdgpu

I installed the latest AMD GPU drivers from their site for AMD 5700XT graphics card. When I did a restart one screen was flickering and my desktop wallpaper was set back to the default screen.

I then went ahead and uninstalled it using the same installer script with the `--uninstall` option passed. I got a success message and restarted to get greeted with the error message for a second or two in the photo below.

[image: Error message]

After this I get put in the tty. I tried to do an update and upgrade to see if it would make a difference and it didn't. I tried booting to different kernel versions and still the same issue. Not really sure how to proceed now.

I'm running 18.04.

Edit: I'm using an AMD CPU - Ryzen 5 3600

Comment: Do you have intel gpu in your processor ? If yes , run the command " sudo modprobe i915" to see if it gets solved.

Comment: And if not , you can use the builtin open-source amdgpu driver in the kernel . Run " sudo modprobe amdgpu " . And even if that doesn't work for you , retry after installing the xorg adapter for amdgpu via " sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu "

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I have an AMD CPU and GPU. In tty I put in the command `sudo modprobe amdgpu` then did a reboot and still in the same situation. No change.

Comment: Did you install xorg-video-amdgpu ?

Comment: And what if you add the line "amdgpu" to the file /etc/modules to load the driver automatically at boot time ?

Comment: Using `apt list | grep amdgpu` didn't show any `xorg-video-amdgpu`. I'll try your next comment now.

Comment: After adding `amdgpu` to `/etc/modules` I have an extra error message that reads: `cgroup1: Unknown subsys name '__DEVEL__sane_behaviour'`. I'm going to undo that change. As less errors are better right :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108528/discussion-between-shmink-and-parsa-mousavi).

Comment: Thanks @ParsaMousavi feel free to add the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to make sure that you have the builtin open-source `amdgpu` driver.Then try inserting the module into the kernel :

```
sudo modprobe amdgpu
```

And also check that you have the adapter for Xorg :

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
```

And then start the X-server via

```
Xorg
```

or

```
startx
```

And if your x-server has gotten deleted  accidentally or by removing the `amdgpu` driver which was installed by the installer ,  try re-installing the server :

```
sudo apt install xorg
```

Reboot to see if it gets solved.

Best regards :)